# Trying to verify a signature, Exception thrown: java.io.IOException: Sequence tag error

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, signature

I'm trying to verify the signature of a message, but I am getting the following exception being thrown.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.SignatureException: Signature encoding error
    at sun.security.rsa.RSASignature.engineVerify(RSASignature.java:185)
    at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineVerify(Signature.java:1140)
    at java.security.Signature.verify(Signature.java:592)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Sequence tag error
    at sun.security.util.DerInputStream.getSequence(DerInputStream.java:280)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSASignature.decodeSignature(RSASignature.java:209)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSASignature.engineVerify(RSASignature.java:174)
    ... 6 more
```

Here is my Java code

```
Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
sig.initVerify(publicKey);
sig.update(message);
return sig.verify(signature);
```

`publicKey` is an instance of `JCERSAPublicKey`

I read on this [website](http://www.globalsign.com/support/faq/tomcat/07.php) that this error is being caused by the *certificate* missing the proper header and footer tags (i.e., `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`). *However*, I am *not* using a certificate, but a *public key*. Looking at my public key PEM file, I can see it has the appropriate headers for a public key.

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
...STUFF
...STUFF
...STUFF
...STUFF
...STUFF
...STUFF
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: That error has nothing whatsoever to do with the key file.

Comment: Yea, I figured that out, hence my solution below. Thanks for trying to help though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit odd, because I thought this would have shipped with Java, but there was no Service Provider for the Signature Algorithm. I downloaded BouncyCastle and after adding it as a provider, the code no longer throws up an exception.

Comment: Can't be, your changing multiple things at the same time and finally something worked so you attribute it to the last thing you did.

Comment: What? How did you come up with this idea: "your changing multiple things at the same time"?

Comment: Wouldn't that have thrown a "NoSuchAlgorithmException" instead?

Comment: @John may you show us an example of the final code ? I'm particularly interested by the "adding it as a provider" part.